# Canopy--python and terminal Python, relations and differences

Tags: python, pip, ipython

I've been using Canopy and IPython notebook especially, most of the time. I installed Python3.4 from Python.org at the very beginning. Since then every time I run my IPython notebook and if there is any packages that I am missing, I download them by using the package manager in Canopy. However, recently I started that tango with Django tutorial project and used a lot of command lines. I installed Python2.7 later, and the related packages by using pip ever since. My question is: what's the relation of Canopy package manager and pip? Because I am not afraid I might have downloaded the same packages and created unnecessary duplicates more than once by using them separately and simultaneously...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Type:

```
which pip
```

It will tell you if pip is pointing to your canopy python directory, or to your system python directory.  I believe that pip will use whatever your system's default python is.  You can figure this out by typing:

```
which python
```

Generally, when I put canopy on a computer, I make canopy the default python (it will prompt you the first time it starts up, and you can set it in the options later).  After I do this, pip will install packages to the canopy python directory.  This layout usually works best for us, because you can still use:

```
python setup.py install
```

To install packages to canopy.